# How to check ldap_search is working? (php)

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to use ldap_search to check if a user exist on a AD database.

This is my code to connect:

```
$ldapconn = ldap_connect("10.0.0.230");
        $clave = "XXX";
        $searchUser = "YYY";
        $ldap_success = false;
        if (ldap_bind($ldapconn, $searchUser, $clave)) {

            $attributes = ['cn'];
            $filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(userPrincipalName=".ldap_escape($post_send['username'], null, LDAP_ESCAPE_FILTER)."))";
            $baseDn = "DC=redcne,DC=cne,DC=cl";
            $results = ldap_search($ldapconn, $baseDn, $filter, $attributes);
            var_dump($results);
            print_r($results);
            exit(0);
```

But `$results` always return false. So, I don't know if:

- I making a mistake with my parameters on `ldap_search`
- The parameters aren't valid

I have to bind first, like this:

```
ldap_bind($ldapconn, $searchUser, $clave))
```

that returns true, I know I can bind to AD, but I don't how to check if I'm doing the `ldap_search` part correctly or I have problem with my permissons or something like that.

UPDATE:
I got the error:

```
ldap_search(): Search: Operations error
```

Comment: why do you have `@` before `ldap_search` ? Do you know what that does ?

Comment: Sorry, wrong code, let me edit it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was on the filter, I had to use another field than 'cn', it was 'samaccountname'. I had to download ALL the info of the AD then I could check whihc field to use. Plus, I had to use userPrincipalName in lowercase to work.

```
$ldapconn = ldap_connect("10.0.0.230");
ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0) or die('Unable to set LDAP opt referrals');
ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3) or die('Unable to set LDAP protocol version');
$searchPass = "XXX";
$searchUser = "YYY";
$ldap_success = false;
if (ldap_bind($ldapconn, $searchUser, $searchPass)) {
    try{
        $post_send['password'] = $searchPass;
        $attributes = ['cn'];
        $filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(samaccountname=".ldap_escape($post_send['username'], null, LDAP_ESCAPE_FILTER)."))";
        $baseDn = "DC=XXX,DC=XX,DC=cl";
        $results = ldap_search($ldapconn, $baseDn, $filter, $attributes);
        $info = ldap_get_entries($ldapconn, $results);
        if ( $info && $info['count'] === 1 ) {
                $ldap_success = true;
        } else {
                $ldap_success = false;
        }
    }
    catch(\Exception $e){
            $ldap_success = false;
    }
}
```